# Mac Catalina Xdebug session won't start

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug, php-7.3

I've just installed Xdebug on Mac Catalina 10.15.4 by following [the Xdebug part of this guide](https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-catalina-apache-mysql-vhost-apc). All went well and I've had no errors while installing Xdebug, but for some reason the Xdebug session never starts when initiated trough PhpStorm.

The steps I've followed were

1. `sphp 7.3`
2. `pecl uninstall -r xdebug`
3. `pecl install xdebug`
4. Removed `zend_extension="xdebug.so"` line from the top of my `usr/local/etc/php/7.3/php.ini`
5. Create file `/usr/local/etc/php/7.3/conf.d/ext-xdebug.ini` with the required Xdebug configuration

Contents of `/usr/local/etc/php/7.3/conf.d/ext-xdebug.ini`

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

Contents of `phpinfo();`

```
xdebug.auto_trace   Off Off
xdebug.cli_color    0   0
xdebug.collect_assignments  Off Off
xdebug.collect_includes On  On
xdebug.collect_params   0   0
xdebug.collect_return   Off Off
xdebug.collect_vars Off Off
xdebug.coverage_enable  On  On
xdebug.default_enable   On  On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.ENV no value    no value
xdebug.dump.FILES   no value    no value
xdebug.dump.GET no value    no value
xdebug.dump.POST    no value    no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION no value    no value
xdebug.dump_globals On  On
xdebug.dump_once    On  On
xdebug.dump_undefined   Off Off
xdebug.file_link_format no value    no value
xdebug.filename_format  no value    no value
xdebug.force_display_errors Off Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting    0   0
xdebug.gc_stats_enable  Off Off
xdebug.gc_stats_output_dir  /var/tmp/   /var/tmp/
xdebug.gc_stats_output_name gcstats.%p  gcstats.%p
xdebug.halt_level   0   0
xdebug.idekey   no value    no value
xdebug.max_nesting_level    256 256
xdebug.max_stack_frames -1  -1
xdebug.overload_var_dump    2   2
xdebug.profiler_append  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value    no value    no value
xdebug.profiler_output_dir  /var/tmp/   /var/tmp/
xdebug.profiler_output_name cachegrind.out.%p   cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_addr_header   no value    no value
xdebug.remote_autostart On  On
xdebug.remote_connect_back  Off Off
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time    3600    3600
xdebug.remote_enable    On  On
xdebug.remote_host  localhost   localhost
xdebug.remote_log   no value    no value
xdebug.remote_log_level 7   7
xdebug.remote_mode  req req
xdebug.remote_port  9000    9000
xdebug.remote_timeout   200 200
xdebug.scream   Off Off
xdebug.show_error_trace Off Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace Off Off
xdebug.show_local_vars  Off Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta   Off Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger Off Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value   no value    no value
xdebug.trace_format 0   0
xdebug.trace_options    0   0
xdebug.trace_output_dir /var/tmp/   /var/tmp/
xdebug.trace_output_name    trace.%c    trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children 128 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data 512 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth    3   3
```

And `php -v`

```
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.20, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.20, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.9.6, Copyright (c) 2002-2020, by Derick Rethans
```

Comment: 1) Enable `xdebug.remote_log` and collect and share the log for such unsuccessful debug session: it will tell where it tries to connect to (if it does it at all) and what the response is. 2) Keep in mind that on Linux and Mac it's very common to have different php settings (different config files) used for CLI and by web server. So make sure you are capturing your phpinfo output using the same way you are trying to debug.

Comment: Very minor side note: you have "remote_autostart On" but your .ini does not have such line. Which suggests either a missing line in copy+paste .. or that you may have more than 1 place where you provide your xdebug settings (as by default that option is Off)

Comment: I've desperately added `xdebug.remote_autostart=1` to the `/usr/local/etc/php/7.3/conf.d/ext-xdebug.ini` after reading some comments on the tutorial by people who couldn't get Xdebug to work either. That should explain the missing line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the issue by adding `xdebug.remote_port=9001` to the ext-xdebug.ini, since executing the command `lsof -nP -i4TCP:9000 | grep LISTEN` shows that `php-fm` is also listening on this port. Note that you also need to change your Xdebug debug port in PhpStorm to 9001 or whatever value you chose.